# MPI_Test returning true flags for requests despite never sending?

Tags: mpi

I have some code that for testing purposes, I removed all sends and only have non-blocking receives. You can imagine my surprise when using `MPI_Test` the flags were indicating some of the requests were actually being completed. I have my code setup in a cartesian grid, with a small replica below, although this doesn't reproduce the error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> // for sleep
#include <mpi.h>



void test(int pos);

MPI_Comm comm_cart;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, j;
    int rank, size;

    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    /* code for mpi cartesian gird topology */
    int dim[1];
    dim[0] = 2;

    
    int periods[1];
    periods[0] = 0;
    int reorder = 1;
    int coords[1];

    MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1, dim, periods, 1, &comm_cart);

    MPI_Cart_coords(comm_cart, rank, 2, coords);

    test(coords[0]);
    
    

    MPI_Finalize();

    return (0);
}



void test(int pos)
{

    float placeholder[4];
    int other = (pos+1) % 2;
    MPI_Request reqs[8];
    int flags[4];

    for(int iter = 0; iter < 20; iter++){

        
        // Test requests from previous time cycle
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            if(iter == 0) break;
            MPI_Test(&reqs[0], &flags[0] , MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            printf("Flag: %d\n", flags[0]);
        }

        MPI_Irecv(&placeholder[0], 1, MPI_FLOAT, other, 0, comm_cart, &reqs[0]);
        
        
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `MPI_Test` and `MPI_PROC_NULL`s. Quite often when using `MPI_Cart_shift`, you end up with `MPI_PROC_NULL`s as if you're on the edge of the grid, a neighbouring cell simply doesn't exist in some directions.

I can't find any documentation for this anywhere, so I had to discover it myself, but when you do an `MPI_Irecv` with an `MPI_PROC_NULL` source, it will instantly complete and when tested using `MPI_Test`, the flag will return true for a completed request. Example code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    
    int t;
    int flag;
    MPI_Request req;
    MPI_Irecv(&t, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_PROC_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req);

    MPI_Test(&req, &flag, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

    printf("Flag: %d\n", flag);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return (0);
}
```

Which returns the following when run:

```
Flag: 1
Flag: 1
```